# Text boxes not setting to values in modal popup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using a modal popup extender which contains a panel having three textboxes and two buttons. I want to fill the textbox values with my specifications (the date selected)..but not getting it successfully.

```
protected void myCal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        TextBoxStart.Text = myCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
        TextBoxEnd.Text = myCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
    }
```

Designer is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">

  <ContentTemplate>        
      <asp:Calendar ID="myCal" runat="server" Height="600px" width="900px" 
        BorderColor="#F2F3F4" BorderWidth="3px" DayStyle-BorderWidth="1px" 
                TodayDayStyle-BackColor="#82CAFF" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" 
        SelectionMode="Day" DayHeaderStyle-Height="30px" 
                TitleStyle-BackColor="#CBE3F0" TitleStyle-ForeColor="#153E7E" 
        OtherMonthDayStyle-ForeColor="#B4CFEC" NextPrevStyle-ForeColor="#2554C7" 
        CssClass="mGrid" onselectionchanged="myCal_SelectionChanged">
        <DayHeaderStyle Height="30px" /><TitleStyle Height="50px" />
        <DayStyle BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CBE3F0" />
    </asp:Calendar>
```

```
      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ButtonDummy" PopupControlID="pnlSelect">

      </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

</ContentTemplate>

      </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>

       <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server" width="200px" Height="200px">

           <table border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: white">
               <tr>
                   <td align="right"></td>
                   <td>
                       <h2>New Appointment</h2>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">Start Date:</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">End Date:</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">Name:</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right"></td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonOK_Click" Text="OK" />
                       <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>

       </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Did you try your .Show() statement after setting textboxes' values?

Comment: myCal control should contains inside modal popup extender

Comment: pankaj do you mean that my calender should be inside modal pop??

Comment: pnlSelect is only Panel or UpdatePanel ?

Comment: its the Panel only...I have update panel also in my code

Comment: try to enveloped your dialog to update panel...

Comment: i just have my panel outside updatepanel..rest everything is inside update panel

Comment: the another way is used Jquery-UI.dialog a fill your textboxes by jquery and by jqury showing and hiding this dialog : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these textboxes placed out of UpdatePanel they are not updated on async request. Place them into the same UpdatePanel or wrap by another one UpdatePanel and set UpdateMode to "Always" like below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSelect" >
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxStart" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxEnd" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Try to set `ChildrenAsTriggers` property of the UpdatePanel1 to `true` or move ModalPopupExtender1 to UpdatePanel2.

Also, you can move PopupExtender and his target dummy button out of the UpdatePanel1 and swap pnlSelect with UpdatePanel2:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDummy" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ButtonDummy"
    PopupControlID="pnlSelect" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxStart" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did you put the popup extender into the updatepanel? It'll need to go in there with the panel.

Comment: my pop up extender and the panel are in two different update panels

Comment: Is there a reason why ModalPopupExtender1 is in UpdatePanel1? It looks to me like it should be in UpdatePanel2

Comment: Remove UpdatePanel2 if you do not need it.